# Stack level too deep when calling remove_from_list from acts_as_list gem

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, acts-as-list

I'm running a test that did not fail before upgrading to rails 5.0, but now I am getting stack level too deep, the test is as follows:

```
describe "item hierarchy" do
    before(:each) do
      @template = FactoryGirl.create(:item_template)
      @root_item_a = FactoryGirl.create(:item, :parent => @template)
      @root_item_b = FactoryGirl.create(:item, :parent => @template)
    end
    it "allows a root item without children to be moved under another item" do
      @root_item_a.parent_item = @root_item_b
      expect(@root_item_a).to be_valid
      expect(@root_item_a.save).to be_truthy

      @root_item_a.reload
      expect(@root_item_a.parent_item).to eql @root_item_b
    end
```

The controller has the following relevant code:

```
belongs_to :parent_item, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'parent_item_id'
has_many :child_items, ->{ order 'position ASC' }, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'parent_item_id', :dependent => :destroy
acts_as_list :scope => [:item_id, :parent_type, :parent_item_id]
validate :parent_items_cannot_have_parents

def parent_items_cannot_have_parents
  if child_items.any? && parent_item.present? # THIS IS LINE  #16
    errors.add(:parent_item, "An item with sub-items should live on the root")
  end
end

def parent_item_id=(item_id)
    if new_record?
      self[:parent_item_id] = item_id
    elsif self[:parent_item_id] != ActiveRecord::Base.connection.type_cast(item_id, self.class.columns_hash['parent_item_id'])
      remove_from_list  # IT FAILS HERE LINE # 30
      self[:parent_item_id] = item_id
      send(:add_to_list_bottom)
    end
  end
```

The stacktrace is:

```
Item item hierarchy allows a child item to be moved under a different parent
     Failure/Error: if child_item.any? && parent_item.present?

     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/scoping.rb:79:in `value_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/per_thread_registry.rb:53:in `value_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/scoping.rb:14:in `current_scope'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:25:in `all'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:124:in `target_scope'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:86:in `scope'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:429:in `scope'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:348:in `empty?'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:50:in `empty?'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:359:in `any?'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:846:in `any?'
     # ./app/models/item.rb:16:in `parent_items_cannot_have_parents'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `catch'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `block in default_terminator'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.7/lib/active_model/validations.rb:408:in `run_validations!'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `block in run_validations!'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.7/lib/active_model/validations.rb:338:in `valid?'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:65:in `valid?'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:82:in `perform_validations'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:230:in `transaction'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:217:in `set_list_position'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:128:in `remove_from_list'
     # ./app/models/item.rb:30:in `parent_item_id='
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `block in check_scope'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `each'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `check_scope'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:770:in `block (2 levels) in deprecated_false_terminator'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `catch'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `block in deprecated_false_terminator'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_update_callbacks'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_update_record'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:81:in `_update_record'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:548:in `create_or_update'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `block in create_or_update'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_save_callbacks'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `create_or_update'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:129:in `save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:230:in `transaction'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:217:in `set_list_position'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:128:in `remove_from_list'
     # ./app/models/item.rb:30:in `parent_item_id='
```

`acts_as_list` gem is using the latest version: `0.9.16`

Comment: It seems like you've got some deep recursion going on.  I know `acts_as_a_list` is a gem so the `remove_from_list` method is not your code, but looking at that may help.  It could be that you have a circular link in the database or something like that.

Comment: We were scheduled to meet up on HackHands, if you have any more questions feel free to ping me there or here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolling back to version 0.9.5 of acts_as_list gem solved the problem

Comment: take a look at what's changed between those two versions and let me know if it's anything we can fix. I'm a maintainer for `acts_as_list`. A PR would be great if you have the time.

Comment: Hi @BrendonMuir the error occurred when calling `.save`, does that tell you anything?

Comment: no not really :) 0.9.5 is quite old now. Can you increment from there each newer version until you get the test breakage and then we can see what was committed on that version that might have changed things for you.

Comment: @BrendonMuir That's what I did and 0.9.5 was the last one that worked

Comment: Ok, now you can get more granular and see which one of the commits in 0.9.6 broke your setup. https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v096-2017-07-05 I suspect it might be the touch changes.